# Update Cover Card for all users

Tags: google-mirror-api

put the case that my glassware app posts news to n users.
As soon as I parse a new news i will insert the new card into user's timeline.
Now put the case that I want to organize the news cards for category ( Sport, Politics, ... )
so now each time I post a new card I want to either post a new cover card or update the already posted one.
Given that as far as i understood the platform each cover card has a unique id per user this means the I need to store server side the id for the cover card for each user and upon update retrieving it and post the update method.
Is this correct or there is another approach I am missing?

KR

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is probably the easiest method - keeping track of the cards that have been inserted for each user. It isn't, however, the only solution available. Glass provides two additional fields that you have control over, *sourceItemId* and *bundleId*, which you can use to insert cards into the Timeline and fetch them out later.

The *sourceItemId* field lets you set each card to an ID that represents the same card in your database. So you would create a news item, assign it an ID in your own database, set this as the *sourceItemId*, and insert this for each user. If you want to get the specific card that represents this item for each user later, you can use `timeline.list` and search by *sourceItemId*.

The *bundleId* is the ID you assign to each card which will be in a bundle to group them together, so multiple cards will have the same bundle ID. You can use `timeline.list` again and specify the *bundleId* to get all the cards in the bundle and then identify and update the one which is marked as the cover card.